# I can not save the value from EditText when closing of the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with EditText. I enter text into EditText. I press the button. I open next fragment . Current fragment  Replace.  How can I save the data entered in the EditText and get them again when I go back to the first fragment? It suggests itself

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("code", getTextField().getText().toString());
        textCode = getTextField().getText().toString();
    }
```

but he did not call. I read and learned that it is called if I wring such a program. I checked and so called. But as I call it when I call a new fragment , and they Replace old? Or maybe there are other options to preserve the value? Static variable global, SHARED preferens - not good.

Answer (score 1):

You can Just save Your Data in `onDestroyView`

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
textCode = getTextField().getText().toString();
}
```